# Custom AMF Serialization on the Client Side Only

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I have a Flex app that needs some custom serialization. I tried to use IExternalizeable. If it worked that would be exactly what I need. But the issue is that I need to do this custom serialization on the client only.

It seems that to get the IExternalizeableized classes read/write methods called the Java classes also have to implement the interface. But the server already has all of the customization that it can handle; that is unfortunately not an option.

I tried to dig into the RPC classes. I was gonna monkey-patch what I needed. But I could only see the classes to handle the (AMF)XML data whereas I have the binary bits flowing.  It appears that all of the serial/deserialization logic is already compiled into the player.  At least that's my guess.

What I am attempting is to take the data from the AMF stream and update objects that already exist.  Currently I am copying the values from the returned objects in my service handlers into the already existing model objects.  I would prefer to skip the step where the NEW items have their values set and instead only set the values on the existing objects.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. If you do custom serialization on the  client, you'll need something on the server to interpret that data.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the classes look like both in AS3 and Flex and explain what you're trying to do with the custom serialization?  There may be another option. And you're right, the AMF deserialization is part of Flash Player itself not the Flex framework.

Comment: I have updated my question with more detail.  Hopefully that will help.